# Clojure Azure authorization - The Date header in the request is incorrect

Tags: clojure, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

I'm having a problem trying to get a valid authentication with Azure Blob Rest API. I'm using an account name, account key and container name, in short using a Shared Key to authenticate, but I'm getting this error every time I try.

:status 403
:reason-phrase Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
The Date header in the request is incorrect.

This is my code:

```clj
(require '[clj-http.client :as http])
(require '[java-time :as jt])

(import javax.crypto.Mac
        javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
        org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64)

(defn- canonicalized-resource [account-name container-name blob-name]
  (str "/" account-name "/" container-name "/" blob-name))

(defn get-authorization-header
  "Returns the Authorization header for a Blob Storage request."
  [account-name account-key request-date request-method content-type canonicalized-resource version]
  (let [string-to-sign (str request-method "\n\n\n\n\n"
                            content-type "\n"
                            "\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                            "x-ms-date:" request-date "\n"
                            "x-ms-version:" version "\n"
                            canonicalized-resource)
        key-bytes (Base64/decodeBase64 account-key)
        key-spec (SecretKeySpec. key-bytes "HmacSHA256")
        mac (Mac/getInstance "HmacSHA256")
        _ (.init mac key-spec)
        signature-bytes (.doFinal mac (.getBytes string-to-sign))
        signature (Base64/encodeBase64String signature-bytes)
        auth-header (str "SharedKey " account-name ":" signature)]
    auth-header))

(defn put-blob [account-name account-key container-name blob-name content-type file-path]
  (let [request-date (jt/format (jt/formatter :rfc-1123-date-time) (jt/zoned-date-time (jt/zone-offset 0)))
        version "2022-11-02"
        request-url (str "https://" account-name ".blob.core.windows.net/" container-name "/" blob-name)
        canon-resource (canonicalized-resource account-name container-name blob-name)
        auth-header (get-authorization-header account-name account-key request-date "PUT" content-type canon-resource version)
        file-content (slurp file-path)
        response (http/put request-url
                           {:body         (Base64/encodeBase64 (.getBytes file-content))
                            :content-type content-type
                            :headers      {"Content-Type"   content-type
                                           "x-ms-date"      request-date
                                           "x-ms-version"   version
                                           "x-ms-blob-type" "BlockBlob"
                                           "Authorization"  auth-header}
                            :debug        true})]
    (if (= (:status response) 201)
      (:body response)
      (throw (Exception. (:body response))))))
```

I went through the docs about authorizing with a shared key and the put operation.

What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't look to me that there's a problem with the way the `request-date` is formatted. Could it be that the auth-header has expired by the time you attempt to use it? According to the docs they last for 15 minutes to avoid reply attacks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-date-header

Comment: I had a problem with the request-date before and the error was more specific, something like the request is too old, which I fixed.